# How to insert element before and after the data value?

Tags: php

code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
     $data[] = array(
                            'city' => $row["city"],
                            'hotel' => $row["hotel_name"]
                        );
}
mysqli_close($con);
$results = json_encode($data);
$json = json_decode($results, true);
foreach($json as $fet)
{
    $datas = $fet['city']." | ".$fet['hotel'].", ";
    echo $datas;
}
```

In this code I have create an autocomplete text box and I want to add `"` before and after data my data look like:

```
delhi | Radisson, noida | Ramada Phuket Deevana Patong, noida | Eco Poplar
```

but I want like this:

```
"delhi | Radisson", "noida | Ramada Phuket Deevana Patong", "noida | Eco Poplar"
```

So, How can I do this ?
Thank You

Comment: `$datas = '"'.$fet['city']." | ".$fet['hotel'].'", ';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put *double quotes* between *single quotes*: `'"'`
**Improvements:** You could save formatted strings while fetching the results. The JSON related functions are useless. Then output using [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode)

```
$data = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
     // double quotes between single quotes
     $data[] = '"' . $row["city"] . ' | ' . $row["hotel_name"] . '"';
}
mysqli_close($con);
// Here I removed useless json_encode/decode functions
// Then output strings separated by a coma
echo implode(', ', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you'll have comma after last element, please try this code:

```
$data = [];
foreach($json as $fet) {
    $data[] = "\"{$fet['city']} | {$fet['hotel']}\"";    
}
echo implode(", ", $data);
```

> **implode():** http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score -2):

```
$data[] = array(
  'city' => $row["city"],
  'hotel' => $row["hotel_name"]
);

$results = json_encode($data);
$json = json_decode($results, true);
foreach($json as $fet)
{
    $datas = '"'.$fet['city']." | ".$fet['hotel'].'"';
    echo $datas;
}
```

Comment: I just added the ' " ' part for his reference, which will return the value he is asking for

Comment: Your foreach will fail, you put `$fet['city']` between single quotes, making use of unexisting constant `city`.

Comment: php code part he needs to check, I checked with delhi | Radisson value which return "delhi | Radisson" as per him

Comment: Test the code you wrote here (copy-paste it), you'll get an error for sure.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.